# How to disable automatic startup of specific hard drives?

Tags: linux, mount, hard-disk

I'd like to have some internal hard drive/s to not spin up automatically when booting or waking from standby on Debian11/KDE.

With the tool *GNOME Disks* I can configure the drives to go into standby after a specified time (like 5 seconds).

Sometimes veracrypt encrypted partitions on the drives are mounted, but this doesn't prevent them from getting put into standby.

I'd like to do so to reduce noise (generated by the drives). It may also be good for reducing power consumption and for the health of the drives.
It would be useful to know whether it would be good for the longevity of the drives to have them mounted often/regularly vs only rarely vs relatively often but put into standby.

I think [*udisks2* could be used for this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062719/how-do-i-disable-the-auto-mounting-of-internal-drives-in-ubuntu-or-kubuntu-18-04) but I don't want to disable the entire service but disable the autostart for specific hard drives only. Is there any GUI one can use to do this if it's possible at all?

Comment: I do not use either, so do not know details. Either systemd-automount or autofs can be used. 
https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/systemd/systemd.automount.5.en.html & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs & https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab#Automount_with_systemd